# How to ignore a property with RestSharp in a Xamarin environment without System.Web namespace

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin, restsharp

I need to prevent some properties of an object from being sent in a RestSharp request. It seems, from another answer, that the normal approach would be to decorate these properties with the following attribute:

[System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnore]

However the Monotouch Xamarin environment does not have a System.Web namespace!

Environment: Xamarin Studio, C#, iOS / Android Project running on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Usually serialization issues are handled by System.Runtime.Serialization. If RestSharp does not support DataContract annotations where IgnoreDataMember attribute is ignore then maybe switch to a different serializer (feature which should be supported by RestSharp).

[IgnoreDataMember] to ignore, [DataMember] to include.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the class you are using for serialization.

If you are using **Newtonsoft.Json** you can do it with: `[JsonIgnore]`